# Thymeleaf th:block condition

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, conditional-statements, thymeleaf

I want to set up some conditions on Thymeleaf templates like this, but it doesn't work.

```html
<table border=2>

<thead>

<tr>  

<td> Identifiant </td>

<td> Nom Formation </td>
<td> Descirption Formation </td>
<td> Adresse Formation </td>
<td>Status Formation  </td>
<td> Chef Projet </td>
<td> Formateur  </td>
<td>Ressource Humain</td>
<td>Update</td>
<td>Liste Devellopeur</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr th:each="formations : ${formations}">
<th:block th:if="${StatusFormation}} =='Traitement' }">
<td th:text="${formations.id}"> </td>
<td th:text="${formations.NomFormation}"> </td>
<td th:text="${formations.DescriptionFormation}"> </td>
<td th:text="${formations.StatusFormation}"> </td>

<td th:text="${formations.AdresseFormation}"> </td>
<td th:text="${formations.chef_projet}"> </td>
<td th:text="${formations.formateurs}"> </td>
<td th:text="${formations.ressourcehumain}"> </td>

</th:block>

</tr> 
</tbody>



</table>
```

the erros is
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${StatusFormation}} =='Traitement' }" (template: "ChefProjetFormationHome" - line 29, col 11) at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:131)

Comment: You have two extra curly braces in that `th:if` expression...... `th:if="${formations.StatusFormation == 'Traitement'}"` should work.

Comment: i resolve this problems : Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression: "${formations.StatusFormation}} =='Traitement' }" (template: "ChefProjetFormationHome" - line 29, col 11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you add one extra brace in this line:

```
<th:block th:if="${StatusFormation}} =='Traitement' }">
```

you should change it to:

```
<th:block th:if="${StatusFormation} == 'Traitement'">
```

Comment: Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${formations.StatusFormation} =='Traitement' }" (template: "ChefProjetFormationHome" - line 29, col 11) i have this problemes ! thank you for youre response !

Comment: hello yes the code works but i dont see a data at my table thymleaf dont use my  conditions